# The algorithm to find the required switches to turn on a light blub

Tags: algorithm, math

Assume you are in a room with `N` switches, and there's a light bulb in the next room. The light bulb is glowing only when some specified switches are all turned on.

Set

- `switches` = the set of all switches. `|switches| = N`.
- `required` = the switches which need to be turned on to make the bulb glowing.

The non-required switches doesn't matter.

You can only check whether the bulb is glowing only if you enter the next room. You can turn some switches on or off, go to the next room to check the bulb, and repeat this process. Let's call this one ATTEMPT.

Assume there is `N` switches, in WORST CASE, what's the minimum number of attempts needed to find out the set of `required` switches (using optimized strategy)?

---

For example,

- `switches = { 1, 2, 3 }`
- `required = { 1, 2 }`

Let's try with an naive approach:

- Turn on `{ 1, 2 }`, the light is glowing. (Ensure switch 3 is not required)
- Turn on `{ 1, 3 }`, the light is not glowing. (Ensure switch 2 is required)
- Turn on `{ 2, 3 }`, the light is not glowing. (Ensure switch 1 is required)

Thus with 3 attempts, we can ensure `required = { 1, 2 }`.

What's the optimized algorithm for this problem?

Let `worst(N)` be the minimum attempt considering `N` switches in worst case. Could you find out `worst(N)`

UPDATE: If you think `worst(N) = N`, could you provide a formal proof?

Comment: it's like a simplified version of bulls and cows.

Comment: In the worst case they're all required and it takes N attempts to verify it. Right? Since each attempt tells you that whether at least one element of a set of switches is required. So you can't increase the number you know is required by more than 1 at a time.

Comment: Could you just please clarify: are the non-required switches *ignored*, or will they switch off the bulb? E.g. will the bulb light up if we switch on every switch including the non-required ones? If so, this could set the grounds for a binary-search approach.

Comment: @PelitMamani. Non-required switches are ignored. Sorry for the unclear description

Comment: @genisage: Intuitively I think you are right, however I'm not sure. Maybe there's a better way to solve this problem in log(N)? If there isn't a better approach, can anyone provide a formal proof?

Comment: Is my answer below formal enough? o.o or do you need more elaboration

Comment: @miaout17 There will be a log(N) solution only if the number of required switches are known and they are either `1 or N - 1`.

Comment: @Ming: I think your condition is too narrow. For instance, if the number of switches is 2, a solution can also be found in `log(N)`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Proof that worst case requires at least N attempts**

If there are N switches, there can be 2^N possible sets of 'required' as each switch can either be in or out of the 'required' set.

To differentiate between the 2^N possible sets, you can think of it as we will need to obtain at least N bits worth of information by fiddling with the switches. If not, there is a possibility that there are more than 1 set that can both fit the information we know so far.

Lets assume that there are 8 possible configurations (N = 3) and we can select a subset of configurations and query whether the 'required' configuration is in the selected subset. The best way to do this would be akin to binary search, achieving a complexity of log(2^N) which is just N attempts. If we use less than 3 attempts, we will be left with at least 2 configurations that we cannot decide which is correct as each attempt will eliminate half of the possible configurations.

Coming back to the original problem, lets assume we use K attempts so far where K < N. Since each attempt will provide 1 bit of information (Yes, it lights up /No, it doesnt light up), each attempt can eliminate half the possible number of configurations, we will be left with 2^(N-K) possible configurations after K attempts.

To get to only 1 distinct possible configuration of the 'required' set, we will need K = N which will give us 2^(N-N) = 2^0 = 1 possible configuration.

This gives us the lower bound for this problem as each attempt will provide 1 bit of information (Yes, it lights up /No, it doesnt light up). Hence we will require at least N attempts.

**Possible solution that uses not more than N attempts**

Since the 'non required switches does not matter', if I interpret it correctly, it means that if switches outside of the 'required' set are turn on, in addition to those in the 'required' set, the light will still be on. As we have N attempts to utilize (and still make it optimal), we can afford to use the following solution:
For each switch (in sequential order), turn on all other switches except for this switch.
Check if light is switched off. If it is switched off, the only switch that remains off will be in the 'required' set.

This solution will use exactly N attempts (even in worse case) and it is one of the optimal solution (as proven earlier).

Comment: I think your description might be right but I'm not sure. Could you formalize the 2nd paragraph with a more mathematical way? Thanks for taking your time to answer my question.

Comment: Thanks for your update. I need some time to think about it. Voted up.

Comment: Accepted. It was nicely explained! Appreciates for taking your time to answer me :)

Answer (score 2):

> Assume there is N switches, in WORST CASE, what's the minimum number of attempts needed to find out the set of required switches (using optimized strategy)?

The brute force way, checking all possible combinations of switches until the light goes on, which would be `O(2^N)` (although we might get lucky and have the light switch on after our first try).

With more optimised searches, the set of required switches can be found in worst case `O(N)` attempts. Here is one way that is always `O(N)`:

- Flip all `N` switches on: we know that the light will be on.
- Turn switch 1 off. If the light goes off, switch 1 is required so turn it back on. If the light stays on, leave switch 1 off because
  it's not required. (One attempt used).
- Turn switch 2 off: If the light goes off, switch 2 is required so turn it back on. If the light stays on, leave switch 2 off because it's not required. (Two attempts used).
- Repeat this check for each of the remaining switches. (`N` attempts used).
- After `N` attempts, we're left with the set of the required switches in the on position.

As noted in other answers/comments, it's also possible that the set of required switches can be found in best case `O(log(N))` and worst case `O(N)`:

- Flip all `N` switches on: we know that the light will be on.
- Flip the first `N/2` switches off. In the light stays on, none of these switches were required, so we can leave the switches turned off. Move to the set of `N/2` switches which are still on and repeat this step...
- If however the light went off, at least one of these `N/2` switches was required: flip the switches back on, split the set in half and repeat the previous step...

This algorithm is worst case `O(N)` because we might have to check each switch individually (e.g. if there are 10 switches and the required configuration is 0101010101).

Comment: I mean, the set of required switches can be found in *best* case `O(1)`. Turn on only switch 1, check to see if the light is on. If it is, you've got your answer right there. If not, you fall back to the linear scan.

Comment: I agree... my answer describes a couple of more optimised strategies than turning on each possible combination of switches. I was addressing the first question ("in WORST CASE, what's the minimum number of attempts needed ... using optimized strategy?")

Comment: Wouldn't the actual worst case be O(N + log(N)) if all the switches were required?

Comment: `O(N + log(N))` is equivalent to `O(N)` (as `N` dominates `log(N)`).

Answer (score -1):

Assume that we need to try every possible combination of the N switches. We can represent then as a binary number say 0101 and we want to check each binary number. A naive approach is just to go through each number in turn: 0000 (all off), 0001 (switch 4 on), 0010 (switch 3 on), 0011 (switch 3 and 4 on). Note how to get from 0001 to 0010 actually takes two steps switching 4 off and 3 on.

A better algorithm called [Gray code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code) runs through each number so that only one digit is switched at each time. The sequence would be 
0000, 0001, 0011, 0010, 
0110, 0111, 0101, 0100,
1100, 1101, 1111, 1110, 
1010, 1011, 1001, 1000.

EDIT: I think this solves a slightly different problem where for the light to be on some switches would need to be off for the light to be on.